# Handling Optional Query Parameters

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

I have a GridView bound to an DataSource query with parameters tied to form controls.

What is the standard / best-practices way to handle optional query parameters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like.. set the control parameter to -1 then in your query do something like...

```
Select * From Blah Where
(Somefield = @param or @param = -1)
```

Answer (score 3):

On your DataSource, have your ControlParam use the DefaultValue:

```
<asp:ControlParameter Name="CustomerID" 
    ControlID="DropDownList1" PropertyName="SelectedValue"  
    DefaultValue="-1" />
```

Then in your SQL statement, check for that same default value from your ControlParameter:

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM Invoices
 WHERE (CustomerID = @CustomerID OR @CustomerID = -1)
```

Comment: @pcampbell: great answer, we think alike